# Unable to style table with css in php

Tags: php, css

I am unable to style the table in css even though i have insert style for the tables.

```
<style>
table, th, td 
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

The above is a simple style for the codes

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="u-full-width">
    <?php


      $result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM register");

  }
  else
  {
      $result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE username LIKE '".$Search."%'");
  }
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>username</th>
  <th>password</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>gender</th>
  <th>age</th>
  <th>Contact</th>
  <th>address</th>
  <th>email</th>
  <th>occupation</th>     
  </tr>";

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td> ";
      echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td> ";
      echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['occupation'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo"</table>";
  mysqli_close($connection);
  ?>
     </div>
     </table>
```

The above is for displaying the tables. May i know what i can do so that it displays the table with the css. Thanks.

Comment: try to add background , to the style definitio, because border in table doesnt works fine

Comment: you have a wrong html structure. remove one of the table tag

Comment: @Bhavik which table tag?

Comment: you have table tag inside a table tag. remove it

Answer (score 0):

Its because your inserting the table dynamically with php.

try this

```
<div class="container">
<table class="u-full-width" border='1'>
<?php

if () {//note code is incomplete, might be copy pasting issue
  $result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM register");

}
else
{
  $result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE username LIKE '".$Search."%'");
}
?>

<tr>
<th>username</th>
<th>password</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>gender</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>occupation</th>     
</tr>

<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td> ";
  echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td> ";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['occupation'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>

</table>
 </div>
 </table>
```

This way your table code is loaded with the page, and any information from the database is dynamically loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can style easily. echo of html is bad practice. so kidly check the below way.

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>username</th>
<th>password</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>gender</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>Contact</th>
<th>address</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>occupation</th>     
</tr>


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
 <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['Username']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['occupation']; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php mysqli_close($connection); ?>
?>
```

and in CSS you can use as before.

`table, th, td 
{
border: 1px solid black;
}`

Hope this will help you!!!